# Can only diamond mods close questions as duplicates of unanswered questions?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

I noticed that [Question B](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/100350/us-b1-b2-visa-not-approved) is closed as a duplicate of [Question A](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/100275/want-to-know-the-reason-of-rejection-of-my-u-s-b1-b2-visa-which-got-refused-un).  I tried to VTC [Question C](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/100413/us-b1-b2-visa-rejected-today) as a duplicate of Question A, but couldn't because Question A is unanswered.

Is closing a question as duplicate of an unanswered question exclusive to diamond moderators?

Comment: If question A and question B are asked by the same person then non-moderators can close them as a dup too.

Comment: FYI, the mjolnir will not allow closure in favour of a unanswered question or in favour of a question where at least one answer is not up voted.  Another reason for awarding copious up votes :)